# jQuery, gmap, google maps streetview issue

Tags: jquery, google-maps

ok, I am using gmap jQuery plugin to create Google Maps. It has a lot of features and seems to work very well.

here is the link to the plugin page:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/

I am plotting my markers using PHP/MySQL/jQuery/JSON---I have the point plotting just as they should.

My issue is that I am trying to display a jQuery modal dialog that contains a street view of the marker. Similar to this:
http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-streetview.html

With my code I end up getting the following error when I click on the marker:

```
gmap h[b] is undefined Source
```

Here is the javascript:

```
$('#map').gmap().bind('init', function (evt, map) {
$.getJSON('controllers/markers.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data.markers, function (i, marker) {
        $('#map').gmap('addMarker', {
            'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude),
            'icon': "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_text_small&chld=bb|" + marker.projectNumber + "|0074b0|FFFFFF|",
            'bounds': true
        }).click(function () {
            var projNum = marker.projectNumber;
            var lat = marker.latitude;
            var lng = marker.longitude;
            var location = $(this).get(0).getPosition();
            map.panTo(location);
            $('#street').dialog({
                'modal': true,
                'width': 530,
                'height': 530,
                'title': projNum,
                'resizable': false,
                'draggable': false
            });
            $('#street').gmap('displayStreetView', 'panel', {
                'position': location
            });
        });
    });
});
```

});

Here is the HTML for the #street div:

```
<div style="display:none;">
        <div id="street" style="height:200px;"></div>
</div>
```

When I alert the: projNum, lat, lng variables I get the correct information.

Any help would be much appreciated.

thanks!